# Flutter BottomNavigator screens with data

Tags: flutter, flutter-bottomnavigation

I am using BottomNavigator in Flutter with four Screens. Two of the Screens have identical names but different data.
Everything works fine except when trying to get from one of the identically named screens to the other one. Is this to be expected?

```
    final screens = [
    Favorites(),
    Search(),
    Trends(language: 'IS'),
    Trends(language: 'EN'),
    ];
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't get the question very well, but can you can try providing `key()` to `Trends()`